# Meta tag 'there is no attribute “class” ' and 'there is no attribute “property” 'and other attribute error

Tags: html, xhtml, meta-tags, meta, xhtml-1.0-strict

I tried to validate my website and I get the following error :

> **there is no attribute "class"**
>
> ```
> <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
> ```
>
> **element "aside" undefined**
>
> ```
> <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
> ```
>
> **there is no attribute "property"**
>
> ```
> <meta property="og:title" content="Growth Scorecard" />
> ```
>
> **document type does not allow element "div" here**
>
> ```
> …+' preptimeline timeline-portion" title="'+titles[parseInt(val)-1]+'"></div>');
> ```

How can I solve this error please suggest to me. I have less knowledge of XHTML. please let me know. why an error occurs on my website.

You can see [validator's error report](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.growthscorecard.com%2F&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&outline=1&group=0&No200=1&verbose=1&st=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3%20http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices#result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements and attributes you are using were introduced in HTML 5.

XHTML 1.0 Transitional is too old to support them.

Use HTML 5 instead. It better reflects what browsers actually support and what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MujahidBhoraniya — as I said: "Use HTML 5"